# Does average value always exist?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limsup-and-liminf

If $a_i \in {\mathbb R}_+$ for all $i \in {\mathbb Z_+}$, and

\begin{align}
\limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i < \infty,
\end{align}

then does the $\lim$ exist? In other words, is there any $c \in {\mathbb R}$ such that

\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i =c.
\end{align}

Notes: $(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i$ does not increase with $n$, even though $\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i$ does. Hence, the **Monotone Convergence Theorem** cannot be applied.

Comment: If $(1/n)\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i$ never increases with $n$ but is bounded below, then it has a limit

Comment: Short answer is no, even if you have a finite lower bound as well as the finite upper bound indicated, the sequence of averages need not converge.

Comment: When the limit exists it is called the Cesaro mean.

Comment: So sorry, the condition should be $a_i \in {\mathbb R}_+$ rather than $a_i \in {\mathbb R}$, and I re-edit this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, thanks to you all!

With your help, I think I can find an counterexample such that $c_n := 1/n \sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ goes between $1/2$ and $1$ infinitely times.

$a_1 = 1$, $a_2=a_3=\varepsilon$, $a_4 = 1-2\varepsilon$, $a_5 =3$, $a_6=a_7=a_8=a_9=a_{10}=a_{11}=\varepsilon$,$a_{12}=1-6\varepsilon$,...

The main idea is

\begin{align}
\frac {1}{1} = 1,c_2,c_3,\frac {2}{4} = \frac {1}{2},\frac {5}{5} =1,c_6,c_7,c_8,c_9,c_{10},c_{11},\frac {6}{12},\ldots
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

No, there are plenty of examples where this fails. Let $a_i=1$ whenever $i$ does not have a 1 in it's decimal expansion. You'll see plenty of such $i$ for $i<1000$ but then suddenly no $i$ in $1000<i<2000$. Then it will jump again. The limsup exists since it is bounded above by $1$. But the average will oscillate forever. To prove this, notice that the average drops below $1/2$ whenever $i\in [10^x,2\cdot 10^x]$ but then is above $1/2$ when $i\in [2\cdot 10^x,3\cdot 10^x]$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the sequence:
$$0,1,-1,2,-2,3,-3,4,-4,\dots$$
The average of the first $n$ numbers are:
$$0,\,\frac12,\,0,\,\frac12,\,0,\,\frac12,\,0,\,\frac12,\,0\dots$$

Comment: So, sorry... I wrongly set the condition $a_i \in {\mathbb R}$... It should be $a_i \in {\mathbb R}_+$

Comment: Still, many thanks to you :-)

Comment: Consider instead $(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,\dots)$, in which the length of each sequence doubles each time. The lim sup is $\frac23$, an average achieved infinitely many times, but the lim inf is $\frac13$.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not.  See if you can make $\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i$ remain between $0$ and $1$, but take value ${} \gt 9/10$ infinitely often and value ${} \le 1/10$ infinitely often.